# Simple Sql Role query issue

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get a user role from the database.

**This works, its just a debug**

```
public String GetRole()
        {
            string role = "";
            string querySQL = "SELECT * FROM Utilizadores WHERE Role LIKE 'admin' ";
            List<Users> lista = new List<Users>();
            try
            {
                //Cria uma instância de ligação à base de dados SQL Server Express
                conn = new SqlConnection(ligacaobd);
                //Abre a ligação à base de dados
                conn.Open();
                //Executa a instrução SQL
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lista.Add(new Users(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3)));
                    role = reader.GetString(3);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return role;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return role;
        }
```

I put this in a button and when I click it, it changes the label to "admin" as it should.

**What i wanted**

```
public String GetRole(string username)
        {
            string role = "";
            string querySQL = "SELECT" +@username+ "FROM Utilizadores";
            List<Users> lista = new List<Users>();
            try
            {
                //Cria uma instância de ligação à base de dados SQL Server Express
                conn = new SqlConnection(ligacaobd);
                //Abre a ligação à base de dados
                conn.Open();
                //Executa a instrução SQL
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lista.Add(new Users(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3)));
                    role = reader.GetString(3);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return role;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return role;
        }
```

I wanted to get the incoming username role but i can't really figure it out.

Create table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Utilizadores] (
[Id_Users] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Username] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Role]     VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT (user_name()) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_Users] ASC)
```

);

Comment: `WHERE Role LIKE ''` Tell us what you think that code does?

Comment: It does nothing, that's where i wanted help

Comment: I tried this : ```string querySQL = "SELECT" +@username+ "FROM Utilizadores";``` and my label goes blank

Comment: What do you **want** the code to do?

Comment: To get me the Role from the user

Comment: Updated above so its easy to read

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this if you want to get all columns

```
string querySQL = "SELECT * FROM Utilizadores WHERE Username=@username";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",username);
```

If you want to get only `Role` column then try this

```
string querySQL = "SELECT Role FROM Utilizadores WHERE Username=@username";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",username);
```

Comment: Be sure to set the type of the column to `VarChar` otherwise index lookups won't work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/